# Spring boot JPA with different parent for entity and service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two different maven projects in first I am trying to keep two modules one for "repository and entities" and second for the services. The second project is containing only one module with the "controllers". Now I am having many problems first is "Not a managed type" for the entities. Another thing if I keep everything in one module or even in different modules with one parent project, it works flawlessly, however, I am just trying to put the different package in different project and module

The entityscan, enablejparepositries and all others are working, the debug states:

```
    name: default
    persistence provider classname: null
    classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@42a57993
    excludeUnlistedClasses: true
    JTA datasource: null
    Non JTA datasource: HikariDataSource (null)
    Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
    PU root URL: file:/F:/Software/MavenRepo/com/company/repo/1.0.0/repo-1.0.0.jar
    Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
    Validation Mode: AUTO
    Jar files URLs []
    Managed classes names [
        com.company.sitemap.repo.Page]
    Mapping files names []
    Properties []
```

However, At the last it states
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.company.sitemap.repo.Page`
and shows error starting the application. 
Can you please help me out with this?

Here is my Application class file

```
package com.company.sitemap;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.company.sitemap.repo.SitemapRepoConfig;
import com.company.sitemap.service.SitemapConfig;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { SitemapRepoConfig.class })
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.nie.learn.sitemap.repo"})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { SitemapConfig.class, SitemapRepoConfig.class })
public class Sitemap extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Sitemap.class, args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

}
```

The entity class resides in different project and module. Let say Project-libs and module module-repo. I am trying to add this as a maven dependency.
The entity file is as follows:

```
package com.company.sitemap.repo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class Page {
```

Repo config to scan repo classes.

```
package com.company.sitemap.repo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration

public class SitemapRepoConfig {

}
```

Service config to scan service classes:

```
package com.company.sitemap.service;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.company.sitemap.repo.PageRepository;

@Configuration
public class SitemapConfig {

    @Bean
    @NotNull
    public SitemapService service(@NotNull PageRepository repo) {
        return new SitemapService(repo);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need all the annotations. Your `@SpringBootApplication` class is in a top-level package `com.company.sitemap` and will detect and activate everything already. I suggest you to remove the `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`, those are all implied already. Also it appears you are running with the wrong clas in `SpringApplicaiton.run` and you should implement the `configure` method for the `SpringBootServletInitializer` if you deploy/build a war.

Comment: I am working with this thing for the last 48 hours I tried everything without success.And yes ```com.company.sitemap``` is top level class but ```com.company.sitemap.repo.Page``` is in jar.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. It will scan the full classpath and the jar should be part of the classpath. So either it isn't on the path or you are manually configuring JPA (you might have included a `persistence.xml` which interferes with the auto config).

Comment: No there is no persistence.xml file in the module.

Comment: There are additional `@Configuraiton` classes not sure why. What is in those, please add them as well as your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Have added Please have a look. Moreover, these config files are there just to let scanner to find the packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205425/discussion-between-ullas-hunka-and-m-deinum).

Comment: I have added all three POM in the chat please join!

Comment: Assuming that your `SitemapService` is an `@Service` (or `@Component`) you don't need a configuraiotn for that. The other one is empty and doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you an example that helps us in a somewhat different case. This kind of config is used for Module1TestConf to allow separate modules testing using Spring boot slicing (@DataJpaTest, etc.) in our multi-module Gradle project to avoid loading all the context.
We just limit our module scanning to the current module + additional entities.

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(
        basePackages = "your.other.module.package.entity",
        basePackageClasses = {SomeEntity1.class, SomeEntity2.class}
)
@ComponentScan(
        value = "your.current.module.package",
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter)})
```

That is basically what is `@SpringBootApplication` is doing under the hood.

So I'm not 100% sure that it would help you. Is there a valid reason to have the projects kept as separate maven projects (use Gradle! :) )?

Anyway, you just need to make those entities scanned by Spring and become manageable...

Also try specifying entity classes directly in `basePackageClasses`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan the package so that spring can create beans automatically. You are defining `Page` as bean but not scanning it. For scan you need to add

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.nie.learn.*" })
```

If you have already added it than please check if `Page` is annotated with `@Entity` like below

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Page {}
```

Comment: I have added the classes please have look!

Comment: Another thing if I keep everything in one module it works flawlessly, however, I am just trying to put different package in different project and module.

Comment: The answer which you are giving is available at every second blog or forum on the internet.

Comment: You need to scan package in different module in the project that you want to use. What I am doing is something like this ```@ComponentScan({"com.*.*.service", "com.*.health"})```. I used * to hide my package names

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { com.company.sitemap.repo})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.company.sitemap.repo"})
public class Sitemap extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Sitemap.class, args);
        for (String name : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

}
```

Try the above configuration.